# jQuery string replace with multiple conditions

Tags: jquery

I have a string in jquery

i want to replace text like `**http:// https://  http://www.  https://www.**`

with test

i know we have a **replace** function  here..

I want to do in one function only.

is it possible 
Thanks

Comment: Use a RegEx replace to match patterns and replace any match. You need to show the code you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a pattern:

```
https?:\/\/(www)?
```

[Here is jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mo_esmp/egmsqdyo/)